# How to break a while loop after some minutes?

Tags: python, time, while-loop, python-datetime

I have a while loop in my python program and I want to `break` from this loop after 5 minutes, I'm currently using the following code:

```
start_time = time.time()
while time.time() - start_time < 300:
    # do something
```

However, it takes added time in each iteration to calculate the `time.time() - start_time < 300:` part. For example, if I use a `for` loop with 30000 iterations and it lasts 5 minutes, the above code does fewer iterations than that.

What should I do about it? I have to break the loop after 5 minutes and I just want to handle this by time, not by `for` loop iterations.

One of my friends suggested [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) package, but I do not know how it works.

Comment: Never rely on the runtime of a program. If you want to do 30,000 iterations use a loop that does exactly that.

Comment: @KlausD. That is exactly my problem, I have to stop my code after 5 minutes and I get better results if I do more iterations, That's why I want to do this. and my code takes different times for different inputs, so I can not calculate the maximum number of iterations for each input.

Comment: Then you ckeck the runtime after every n-th iteration and `break` if time is up.

Comment: at the risk of stating the obvious, with tight loops where `time.time()` is significant, be careful in your analysis if you are using profiling ( as in `cProfile`), as the profiling itself will alter the timing.

Comment: given all these answers - what is the remaining difficulty that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

I think using threading and sleep is the best approach.  You can do it in a simple way using a lambda function to create a sleeping background thread and simply check if if the thread is still running inside your loop (break the loop when time is up):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

fiveMinutes = Thread(target=lambda:sleep(300)) # 5 min sleeping thread (300 seconds)
fiveMinutes.start() # start wait time

for i in range(10**10): # <-- this represents your loop condition
    # ...
    if not fiveMinutes.is_alive(): break # break after 5 minutes elapsed
    # ...
```

This should add less overhead to your processing loop so the timed out iterations should be very close to the effective time to process the same number of iterations.

**[EDIT] Thread/sleep vs time.time()**

I made a few more tests and there is very little difference between using the sleeping thread and an optimal use of the time() function.   The overhead is less than a microsecond per iteration:

```
from time import time

fiveMinutes = time() + 300

for i in range(10**10): # <-- this represents your loop condition
    # ...
    if time() > fiveMinutes : break # break after 5 minutes elapsed
    # ...
```

If you are getting a 3 seconds difference over a 1 minute sample, I would suspect that the processing time of your logic has its own variability (i.e. running the same number of iterations in a loop will vary from one run to the next).  Either that or you are checking for timeout a lot more often than the 11,311 iterations would suggest (perhaps by checking inside a nested loop).  In my tests the two approaches varied by less than 0.5 second over a 60 second sample executing 41,000 iterations: +0.37sec for time() and +0.23sec for thread.

Answer (score 0):

> the above code does fewer iterations than that.

A likely reason is that checking the time itself takes time. Therefore, you could check the time less often:

```
start_time = time.time()
lv = 0
while True:
    if lv == 100: # check time only once in 100 iterations
        if time.time() - start_time > 300:
            break
        else:
            lv = 0

    # do something

    lv +=1
```

Comment: is it really that helpful?  There are a lot of iterations in 5 minutes!

Comment: and I think it is >300 not <300

Comment: @NotFounded it should reduce the time spent for checking the time to 1% with respect to your current solution. You can even reduce it further by increasing `100` to a higher number. At a certain point, you trade efficiency (not checking the time more often than neccessary) for accuracy (terminating the loop after exactly 5 minutes).

Comment: why not use `(lv % 100) == 0`? and maybe a huge `lv in range(0,999999999)` on the idea that range will be more optimized than `+=`-ing *manually*  @Not_Founded done well, it should cut 90%+ of your time sampling, if you can tolerate the reduced time resolution implied by only testing every 100 iterations.

Comment: @JL Peyret  ... my line of thinking was that I want to avoid huge integers generated by counting up for minutes and assumed resetting `lv`to 0 will not take long compared to the time check. At the same time I have no strong objections against a modulo division. I'd guess, both will work without much of a performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like need of implementing timeout for me. You might use built-in `threading` module to do it following way:

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Event

stop = Event()

def function():
    while not stop.is_set():
        print('*')
        time.sleep(1)

thread = Thread(target=function)

thread.start()
thread.join(timeout=60)
stop.set()
```

Above code simply prints `*` every second for `60` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

*(a bit of tinkering later, I think I broadly agree with Alain.  I get a significant speed up from just breaking after a certain number of iterations, but whether using a thread, time.time directly or a partial sampling approach, pretty much all of them end up degrading loop time.  `time.time()` itself is probably already fairly highly optimized, so all the extra booleans and stuff to avoid using it too much probably don't improve things much).*

Don't know if it's more efficient, but you could try a thread and a shared mutable object to drive the loop.  Here's a test at 0.5 seconds.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def myfunc(mutable_):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mutable_.value = False
    print("done")


class Mutable:
    value = True

mutable_ = Mutable()

t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(mutable_,))

start = time.time()
t.start()
while mutable_.value:
    print(time.time() - start)
```

The unknown here to me is whether the loop's attribute access to `mutable_.value`, which doesn't need to involve the thread directly is that much cheaper than polling the thread itself.

Now, in my test, there was a bit of a difference where the thread had not yet updated the value so the loop ran a bit over compared to using own local time check.  Might be possible to set your thread time out at 299.9 seconds, get close and finish more carefully.

Here's a v2 using thread sleeping to get most of the way there (that 0.49) and a, normally short-circuited `time.time()` check to finalize.

```
def myfunc(mutable_, looptime):
    time.sleep(looptime)
    mutable_.value = False

t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(mutable_,.49))

t.start()
start = time.time()

while mutable_.value or (time.time() - start <= .5):
    print(time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this following:

```
start_time = time.time() + 300
while True:
    if time.time() > start_time:
         break
```

Comment: I tried this, for example for one minute, it did 11311 iterations, but with for loop 11311 iterations took 47 seconds to be done.